# ruby new create error, unable to understand

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to ruby on rails, and am planning to learn it.

However I'm unable to understand the following error.

Please explain me. Also tell me how to resolve it.

This is the command I ran,

```
rails new Documents/rails/first/
```

This is the error:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:230:in `activate': can't activate rack (~> 1.4.5, runtime) for ["actionpack-3.2.13", "railties-3.2.13"], already activated rack-1.5.2 for ["rack-ssl-1.3.3", "railties-3.2.13"] (Gem::LoadError)
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:246:in `activate'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:245:in `each'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:245:in `activate'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:246:in `activate'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:245:in `each'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:245:in `activate'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1056:in `gem'
        from /usr/bin/rails:18
```

Comment: what command did you run before getting that error?

Comment: Post edited. Please have a look at it

Comment: Nobody knows it? cant explain?

Answer (score 0):

You might have a clash loading dependencies.

At a guess you could try:

```
bundle install
bundle exec rails new Documents/rails/first/
```

. . . this is very commonly needed in rails environment. The `bundle exec` command ensures you run with gem dependencies as specified in the application's `Gemfile` when any code calls `require "this-or-that-gem"` (and `bundle install` ensures you have installed all the gems listed in that file)

Comment: bundle install says "Bundler::GemfileNotFound", The next command says "Could not locate Gemfile", I installed rails using gem install rails -y, if needed

Comment: Did you run command in the base folder of your application? If 'no', please try from that location. If 'yes', then I am sorry but my guess for your problem is wrong. You'll need Bundler later though . . .

Comment: Oh, hang on, you are trying to create your first rails app? My answer is plain wrong, sorry!